# How to Send Text and Image File Data at The Same Time to MySQL Database Without Refreshing The Page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I don't know how to send `text`, `checkbox`, `radio` data and also `image file` at the same time using ajax jquery post (in order not to refresh the page).

Here are the codes I have.

> index.php

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
    Your Name : <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

    <BR>

    Your Sex : 

    <input type="radio" class="get_gender" name="gender" id="genderM" value="Male">Male
    <input type="radio" class="get_gender" name="gender" id="genderF" value="Female">Female

    <BR>

    Your Hobbies : 

    <input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="basket" id="basket" value="Basketball">Basketball
    <input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="foot" id="foot" value="Football">Football
    <input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="volley" id="volley" value="Volleyball">Volleyball

    <BR>

    Your Grade : 

    <select name="grade" id="grade">
        <option value="1>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <BR>

    Upload Photo : <input type="file" name="image" id="image">

    <BR>

    <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onclick="save()">
</form>
```

> save.php

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

$usename = $_POST['username'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$photo = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$sql = "insert into user
(username, gender, hobby, grade, photo)
values('$username','$gender','$hobby','$grade','$photo')";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

header("location: index.php");
?>
```

> index.js

```
function save(){

    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;

    var hobby = [];
    $('.get_hobby').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            hobby.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    hobby = hobby.toString();

    var gender = [];
    $('.get_gender').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            gender.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    gender = gender.toString();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'save.php',
        data: {
            username: username,
            hobby: hobby,
            hobby: hobby,
            grade: grade
        },
        success: function(result){
        }
    });
}
```

Please help

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @Nick I have problem in sending the text and image file `at the same time` to mysql database without refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your `save` function - and send both form data and an image at the same time by using a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object:

```
function save_data() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#userform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test13.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Note you need a couple of other changes. The form needs an `id` attribute e.g.

```
<form id="userform">
```

You should change the `name` attributes of the hobbies to `hobby[]` i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="hobby[]" id="basket" value="Basketball">Basketball
<input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="hobby[]" id="foot" value="Football">Football
<input type="checkbox" class="get_hobby" name="hobby[]" id="volley" value="Volleyball">Volleyball
```

And you need to add

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

To your ajax object.

In your PHP code, you would need to assemble `$hobby` from the raw form values:

```
$hobby = implode(',', $_POST['hobby']);
```

and you should include a check for `$_POST['gender']` being set:

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'] ?? '';
```

I needed to change the name of your function as `save` was causing conflicts. I renamed it to `save_data`. You may not find this is an issue.

Comment: The database doesn't receive the radio button and checkbox data, bro. Is there any solution?

Comment: @VanesticaIreline see my edit. `gender` should work fine - you should see either `$_POST['gender'] = 'male'` or `$_POST['gender'] = 'female'`, and the code I have added will give you a comma separated list of the checked boxes for `hobby`.